# Array goes empty/undefined in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

My functionality is based on data formatting with current structure and WS. My code is getting data and rearrange in a new structure by js/jquery. It is working fine in all browsers and mobile devices except IE. It is not working in any of IE versions. WS data is coming in "wrapper" and i again get and set it in two div's that are "lDiv" and "rDiv". Code is here for more clarification:

```
    var firArr = new Array();   

    function firstFn(){  
        firArr = $("#container").find(".wrapper");
        var len = firArr.length;
         $("#container").html("");

        $("#container").append('<div class="lDiv"></div><div class="rDiv"></div>');

         for(var x=0; x < len ; x++){
             var html="";                
             if(x % 2 != 0){    
                html = firArr[x];                    
                $(".rDiv").append(html);
             }
            else{           
                html = firArr[x];           
                $(".lDiv").append(html);
            }
        }       
    }
    firstFn();
```

Comment: this `firArr = $("#container").find(".wrapper")` might return nothing ?

Comment: can you prepare a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: no in array complete data inserting but in IE at the time of looping it will null or undefined it shows in IE "0" inside the for loop

Comment: data came and blank when i run this code  $("#container").html(""); after that array is not null and inside the loop it will goes blank ......... and as per my question it is working fine in all browsers including FF and chrome

Comment: when i am creating example in local machine it works in IE also but problem is when it is on server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE seems to not have a reference to your elements once you remove them from the DOM. Use a temporary container to solve this:

```js
function firstFn(){  
    var temp = $('<div class="lDiv"></div><div class="rDiv"></div>');
    
    $("#container .wrapper").each(function(i,o){                                  
        temp.eq(i % 2).append(o);
    });

    $("#container").html(temp);  
}

firstFn();
```

```css
.lDiv, .rDiv{ float: left; width: 30%; padding: 1em; margin: 5%; background: #edeced }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="wrapper">1</div>
    <div class="wrapper">2</div>
    <div class="wrapper">3</div>
    <div class="wrapper">4</div>
</div>
```

In the code above, `temp` is a jQuery Object that references 2 divs (`.lDiv` and `.rDiv`). The first one can be accessed by doing `temp.eq(0)`, and the second, by `temp.eq(1)`.

In the `$.each` function, `i` is the index of the current element, `o` is a reference to it.

Doing `.eq(i % 2)` will result in alternatively selecting the left and right divs so you can append stuff to it.

Comment: it works in IE and other thanks a lot for effective and quick answer blex. I want to know one thing how assign values in ldiv and rdiv it is like magic for me

Comment: Glad to help, @Anup. Was your comment a question? I added some explanations.

Comment: i cant add more then one plus otherwise i will, thanks a lot for description also